# Java class unused

Tags: java, class, console

I made a simple java program that works on console and I have a error I never had before.
There are no errors in my code but for some reason I can't run the program cause of my 'public class serie' that is never used.

this my code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class serie {
public final void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final int BASE = 36;
    final BigInteger MODULO = new BigInteger("ZV", BASE);;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String strChassisNummer;
    String input = "y";

    while (input == "y"){
        try{
            System.out.print("Geef een chasis nummer in:");
            strChassisNummer = keyboard.nextLine();
            BigInteger chassisNummer = new BigInteger(strChassisNummer,
                    BASE);

            BigInteger remainder = chassisNummer.remainder(MODULO);
            System.out.print(strChassisNummer);
            System.out.print(";");
            String paddedRemainder = remainder.toString(BASE);
            if (paddedRemainder.length() == 1)
            {
                System.out.print("0" + paddedRemainder.toUpperCase());
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(paddedRemainder.toUpperCase());
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Wenst u nog een chasis nummer in te geven ? (y/n): ");
            input =keyboard.nextLine();

            if (input != "y"){
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you mean ` public static void main `?

Comment: Do you get a message?  Does it crash your machine?  Does it set your house on fire?  What happens that isn't supposed to happen when you run the code?

Comment: @rcook I'm going to have nightmares about my code setting my house on fire now.

Comment: @Cruncher I hope it never does, in fact I hope that never happens.  But if it does and you want someone on SO to answer a question about it, be sure to put it in your question ...

Comment: @rcook Great, you made me laugh at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `final` use `static` modifier to the `main` method. The `main` method should be static with signature allows it to be the entry point of the runnable class.

Answer (score 9):

Declare your main method as static, not final. Why have you declared it final in the first place?

Comment: +1 There is not much incremental testing here `(input != "y")` is always true.

Answer (score 1):

Your main needs to be static.

Non-static methods require the class to be instansiated and Java doesn't instantiate your class by magic.

Answer (score 0):

Java starts running a program with the specific

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

signature.
So your main method should be

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

and not

```
public final void main (String[] args)
```